# How do I find x and y gradient in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement a custom version of Histogram of Oriented Gradients. My gradient kernel is [-1.2 0 1.2]. This kernel has to be applied in x and y directions (along rows and along columns), to find the image gradients in x and y directions G<sub>x</sub> and G<sub>y</sub>.

In Matlab this would be something like

```
hx = [-1.2 0 1.2]
hy = hx'                        %transpose
Gx = imfilter(double(I),hx)     %Gx is the gradient along x, I is the image
Gy = imfilter(double(I),hy)     %Gy is the gradient along y
```

How do I do this in OpenCV ? I looked at create createSeparableLinearFilter, but it seems to give some sort of sum of Gx and Gy. I need to find Gx and Gy separately.
I am looking for something like

```
Ptr<FilterEngine> Fx = createRowFilter(...);
Ptr<FilterEngine> Fy = createColumnFilter(...);
Fx->apply(img, Gx, ...);  //Gx is x gradient, Gx and Gy are float or double
Fy->apply(img, Gy, ...);  //Gy is y gradient
```

Of course this can be done by writing my own for loop, visiting every pixel, but I was wondering whether there is any OpenCV way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for
[filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#filter2d)

use it each time with a different kernel.

Solution from Mathai:

```
float kernelY[9] = {0,-1.0,0,0,0,0,0,1.0,0};
float kernelX[9] = {0,0,0,-1.0,0,1.0,0,0,0};
Mat filterY(3, 3, CV_32F, kernelY);
Mat filterX(3, 3, CV_32F, kernelX);
filter2D(img,dsty,-1 ,filterY, Point( -1, -1 ),0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
filter2D(img,dstx,-1 ,filterX, Point( -1, -1 ),0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
```

Comment: SepFilter2d also gives a 2d filtered output, not Gx and Gy separately according to the definition -                        void sepFilter2D(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int ddepth, InputArray kernelX, InputArray kernelY, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1), double delta=0, int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT ). NOte that there is only one output dst.

Comment: yes, based on your answer, I figured it out. Here is the solution, just in case somebody else is looking for it
  float kernelY[9] = {0,-1.0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0};
  float kernelX[9] = {0,0,0,-1.0,0,1.0,0,0,0};
  Mat filterY(3, 3, CV_32F, kernelY);
  Mat filterX(3, 3, CV_32F, kernelX);

  filter2D(img,dstx,-1 ,filterY, Point( -1, -1 ),0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
  filter2D(img,dsty,-1 ,filterX, Point( -1, -1 ),0, BORDER_DEFAULT );

Comment: Great :) make sure you swap between dsty dstx.

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html) to make your own custom kernels. I think you need to make an NxN kernel for OpenCV to recognize it properly (basically it will be `hx; hx; hx` for `Gx`).

HTH

Comment: Thanks..based on both answers I found the solution. Unfortunately I can accept only one answer :)